# Write a user defined class in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have class in `libraries/myclass.php` and a function named `myFunction`. Also I try to call that function in my controller with the following  code

```
$myclasobj=new libraries\Myclass();
$returnvalue=$myclasobj->myFunction($para);
```

results that class not found. I dont want it as a helper class and auto load this class. I just want to use as a simple class.I am using laravel 4.How can I obtain this?

**Update**
Thanks all of you for your great help.
As per @carousel,@Ohgodwhy I make it by namespacing (Actually before I don't know about it).
I make a directory under libraries named `mylib` and move my class (`myclass.php`) to it and after that I add `namespace mylib;` to the top of `myclass.php`. 
And after that I add `use mylib\Myclass;` to my controller.
Finally I add these lines  to composer.json

```
,
 "psr-0": {
        "mylib": "app/libraries"
    },
```

After these things my class is working.Thanks to all for helping me

Comment: where is your namespace being defined? `libraries` does not indicate the directory in this case, you're using a namespace to access that class, but it doesn't exist within that namespace.

Comment: wait i try with name space

Comment: i try with namespace <code>use app\libraries\Myclass;</code> but stills  error

Comment: Every one got down-vote here . What the reason ?

Comment: I dont know. I didn't make any downvotes..

Comment: I don't think there's enough information in the questions for anyone to give a good answer. There could be many reasons it can't find a class - doe you have an autoloader? is it set up to load your actual class in (either through classmap or PSR-0/4)? Does your class's namespace correspond to its path (if PSR-0/4) and/or the way you're calling it? That's definitely my off-the-top-of-my-head list of things to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every new class, in order to be used in Laravel, has to be linked to Application. It can be done in more then one way:

```
Through class map
With namespacing
By its path
```

In that sense there is no simple classes. All classes can become a part of Laravel Application flow, if they are referenced correctly with composer.

UPDATE TO MY ANSWER:

Here is a [link](https://laracasts.com/lessons/decoding-facades) to best resource that explaines facades.

Comment: I would recommend not using the `path`, and regarding `class map`, in laravel it's referred to as the `Facade Classes`

Comment: Can you please give some examples of using this

Comment: I dont quite understand, but I wanted to say how it can be done like this. Best practice is to namespace all classes.

Comment: manuthalasseril please reref to some good composer/laravel tutorial.
It is a large topic, that cant be covered here.

Comment: I would like to see arguments for voting down my post.

Comment: Jeffrey Way on Laracasts has awesome Laravel tutorials. There are screencasts dedicated to composer, namespacinc. So checkout, you wont regret.

Comment: i upvoted all the answers to negotiate the unreasonable downvote. none the less, __Facades__ make life easier. should have been mentioned.

Comment: Thank you very much - I like playing fair :)
I didnt want to talk about facades, since it would complicate things more.

Comment: carousel Ohgodwhy thanks for the help.carousel Ohgodwhy  itachi  By the by what is Facade Classes. Can you please give some tutorial link  about it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the file hasn't been loaded yet, the proper way to add your **libraries/** directory to the classloader would be to modify your composer.json to add the directory to the autoloader.

```
autoload: {
    classmap: [
        "...",
        "libraries/"
    ]
}
```

After that, you'll need to rebuild the autoloader, so in the home directory, go ahead and run this in your terminal:

```
$ php artisan dump-autoload -o
```

Also ensure that your class is actually contained inside a namespace, because using

```
new libraries\myClass();
```

Does not load "myClass" from the "libraries" folder. It would be helpful if you could add it to the original question.

Comment: It should be classmap, and composer dumpautoload

Comment: @carousel Using artisan is more static as I don't know where the asker's composer is installed. And it would be ```composer dump-autoload``` (with a hyphen) there too as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this, it should solve your problem:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    app_path().'/commands',
    app_path().'/controllers',
    app_path().'/models',
    app_path().'/database/seeds',
    app_path().'/classes', //we added this
    ));
```